# How to solve: type 'Padding' is not a subtype of type 'IconData' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am not understanding the error and where it is. Can you help me please?

This is the error message:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building:
type 'Padding' is not a subtype of type 'IconData' in type cast

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      TodayTaskView.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:taskly/app/modules/home/views/today_task_view.dart:151:31)
```

And this is my homepage view code:

```
import 'package:bubble_bottom_bar/bubble_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:taskly/app/global_widgets/bottom_sheet.dart';
import 'package:taskly/app/modules/home/controllers/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:taskly/app/theme/text_theme.dart';

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  final controller = Get.put(HomeController());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.getUser();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Obx(() => controller.navBarSwitcher()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          controller.controllerReset();
          showModalBottomSheet(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return BottomSheetContent(
                buttonText: 'Create Task',
                onSubmit: () {
                  controller.addTask();
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        elevation: 3,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
        () => BubbleBottomBar(
          opacity: 0,
          fabLocation: BubbleBottomBarFabLocation.end,
          currentIndex: controller.currentIndex,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16)),
          hasInk: false,
          elevation: 7,
          inkColor: Colors.black54,
          hasNotch: true,
          onTap: (index) => controller.currentIndex = index,
          items: [
            BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              title: Text(
                'Home',
                style: kSub2HeadTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              icon: Icon(
                // FontAwesomeIcons.home,
                FontAwesomeIcons.house,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
              ),
              // activeIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home,
              activeIcon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.house,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
            BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              title: Text(
                'Tasks',
                style: kSub2HeadTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.listUl,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.listUl,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
            // BubbleBottomBarItem(
            //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            //   title: Text(
            //     'To-do',
            //     style: kSub2HeadTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
            //   ),
            //   icon: Icon(
            //     FontAwesomeIcons.tasks,
            //     color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            //   ),
            //   activeIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tasks,
            //       color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

While this is my today_task_view code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:taskly/app/global_widgets/bottom_sheet.dart';
import 'package:taskly/app/global_widgets/expandable_container.dart';
import 'package:taskly/app/modules/home/controllers/home_controller.dart';
import 'package:taskly/app/theme/text_theme.dart';

class TodayTaskView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: Get.height,
      width: Get.width,
      color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 50),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 25, right: 25),
            child: Text(
              'Today\'s Tasks',
              style: kSubHeadTextStyle.copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.012),
          GetBuilder<HomeController>(
            id: 1,
            builder: (controller) {
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final task = controller.todayTasks[index]!;
                    return Slidable(
                      // actionPane: SlidableBehindActionPane(),
                      // actionExtentRatio: 0.2,
                      // controller: controller.slideC,
                      child: ExpandedContainer(
                        icon: task.taskImage,
                        title: task.taskTitle,
                        time: task.startTime,
                        desc: task.taskDesc,
                      ),
                      // actions: [
                      //   Padding(
                      //     padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      //         bottom: Get.width * 0.05,
                      //         left: Get.width * 0.07),
                      //     child: Container(
                      //       padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      //       width: 40,
                      //       height: 40,
                      //       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      //           color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                      //           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      //       child: IconButton(
                      //           icon: Icon(
                      //             Icons.edit,
                      //             size: 26,
                      //             color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      //           ),
                      //           onPressed: () {
                      //             controller.slideC.activeState?.close();
                      //             Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                      //             controller.preUpdateTask(task);
                      //             showModalBottomSheet(
                      //               backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      //               isScrollControlled: true,
                      //               context: context,
                      //               builder: (context) {
                      //                 return BottomSheetContent(
                      //                   buttonText: 'Update Task',
                      //                   onSubmit: () {
                      //                     controller.updateTask(task);
                      //                   },
                      //                 );
                      //               },
                      //             );
                      //           }),
                      //     ),
                      //   ),
                      // ],
                      // secondaryActions: [
                      //   Padding(
                      //     padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      //         bottom: Get.width * 0.05,
                      //         right: Get.width * 0.07),
                      //     child: Container(
                      //       padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      //       width: 40,
                      //       height: 40,
                      //       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      //           color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                      //           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      //       child: IconButton(
                      //           icon: Icon(
                      //             Icons.delete,
                      //             size: 26,
                      //             color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      //           ),
                      //           onPressed: () {
                      //             controller.slideC.activeState?.close();
                      //             Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                      //             controller.customDialogDel(context, task);
                      //           }),
                      //     ),
                      //   ),
                      // ],
                      startActionPane: ActionPane(
                        motion: BehindMotion(),
                        children: [
                          SlidableAction(
                            onPressed: (context) {
                              // controller.slideC.activeState?.close();
                              Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                              controller.preUpdateTask(task);
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                isScrollControlled: true,
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return BottomSheetContent(
                                    buttonText: 'Update Task',
                                    onSubmit: () {
                                      controller.updateTask(task);
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            icon: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: Get.width * 0.05,
                                left: Get.width * 0.07,
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.edit,
                                  size: 26,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ) as IconData,
                            label: "Update",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      endActionPane: ActionPane(
                        motion: BehindMotion(),
                        children: [
                          SlidableAction(
                            onPressed: (context) {
                              // controller.slideC.activeState?.close();
                              Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                              controller.customDialogDel(context, task);
                            },
                            icon: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: Get.width * 0.05,
                                right: Get.width * 0.07,
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.delete,
                                  size: 26,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ) as IconData,
                            label: "Delete",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: controller.todayTasks.length,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have the following line in your code (twice), in `class TodayTaskView`:

```
 ) as IconData,
```

And `SlidableAction` wants an `IconData`, and `Padding` can't be cast to an `IconData`

[`IconData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconData-class.html) is not a widget, it is just a description of an icon. It holds an `int`, two `String`'s and a `bool`.

`Padding` is a widget.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I tried to solve by casting icondata and removing padding, but I get the same error

Comment: What? The only thing you can put into the `icon:` field is e.g. `Icons.delete`, or similar. You cannot have the `Container` and you cannot have the `Icon`. Those are widgets as well. You can ONLY have IconData. Don't cast anything.